# iterate through nested json object and get values in table with python

Tags: python, json, nested-lists, reportlab, invoice

i have a json data like

```
    "preference":[
                {
                  "access":"true1",
                  "visibility":"false1"
                },
                {
                  "access":"true2",
                  "visibility":"false2"
                },
                {
                  "access":"true3",
                  "visibility":"false3"
                },
           ]
```

i want to access the list objects and display every list element in table format

```
    for item in data['preference']
         print(item)
      
     TableData = [
             [item.get('access'),item.get('visibility')]
             ]
```

this prints only the last item

```
           {
              "access":"true3",
              "visibility":"false3"
            },
```

in table format
please suggest me some code to access every element in table format asap
Thank you in Advance..

Comment: I can't understand the question. Please fix your formatting (indentation is meaningful in Python) and show the exact expected output as well as the actual output.

Comment: Because ```item``` is assigned the last value

Comment: ```TableData = [[item.get('access'),item.get('visibility')]for item in data['preference']]```?

Comment: "access" is for retrieing data, "in table format" is for outputting data

Comment: Fix your code indention *and* use correct upper case letters. Help the helpers to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is you are not appending to the `TableData` `list`, you are just adding it, so as you go on adding the element to the list it **overwrites** the last element.
Here is the code where you will get the expected output:

```
data = {
"preference":[
                {
                  "access":"true1",
                  "visibility":"false1"
                },
                {
                  "access":"true2",
                  "visibility":"false2"
                },
                {
                  "access":"true3",
                  "visibility":"false3"
                },
           ]
}
TableData = []
for item in data['preference']:
    print(item)
    TableData.append([item.get('access'),item.get('visibility')])
    
print (TableData)
```

Output:

```
[['true1', 'false1'], ['true2', 'false2'], ['true3', 'false3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only display the data, you don't any container to save the data

```
for item in data['preference']:
    print(f"{item.get('access')} | {item.get('visibility')}")
```

But if you want to sav them, use a list around

```
# FIX YOUR COE
TableData = []
for item in data['preference']:
    TableData.append([item.get('access'), item.get('visibility')])

# IMPROVE
TableData = [[item.get('access'), item.get('visibility')] for item in data['preference']]

print(TableData)  # [['true1', 'false1'], ['true2', 'false2'], ['true3', 'false3']]
```